How to make specific elements inside custom modal appear above an overlay with higher z-index than the modal?
Context:
In my Blazor web app I am trying to implement a feature which will allow me to cover all elements, except some selected ones, with an overlay. Only selected (highlighted) elements should be visible above the overlay.
So far everything worked by changing the class of the elements I wanted to highlight dynamically to a highlighted class which has higher z-index than the overlay element.
The problem:
When I use my custom modal, the elements inside don't appear in front of the overlay even when I apply the highlighted class.
Minimal example:
Here link to jsfiddle (same code as below): https://jsfiddle.net/r3qub4k5/
<div class="overlay"> </div>
    
<div class="custom-modal-background">
    <div class="custom-modal" >
        <div class="modal-div">
          <div class="highlighted">
            I want to be in front of everything
          </div>
          <div>
            I need to be covered
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="highlighted">
  I am in front of everything
</div>

<div>
  I am not in front of everything
</div>

.custom-modal-background {
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    z-index: 1500; 
}
.custom-modal {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    background-color: white;
}

.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    z-index: 2000;
}

.highlighted {
    position: relative;
    background-color: yellow;
    z-index: 2100;
}

Suspect reasons:
I think that the reason is that the custom-modal-background and custom-modal elements have position: fixed which creates their own stacking context (this property is necessary for them to work properly). Removing the position: fixed property solves the problem but is not a solution for me (unless I find a way to implement my modal without needing this property)
What I have tried:
I tried using a Blazor bootstrap modal instead of my custom one but the problem wasn't solved. Also Chat-GPT proposed moving the element inside DOM using JSInterop but I don't know if that would be a scalable solution. (I would appreciate some thoughts about this also)
Removing z-index completely is not a solution for me, since some elements in the modal need to appear behind the overlay if they don't have the highlighted class.
Question:
Is there a way to make the highlighted elements inside the custom-modal appear above the overlay elements while keeping the elements inside the modal without the highlighted class behind?
I am looking for a solution that is scalable as I will be using it for many elements which I will mark as highlighted.
Many thanks!

You should set z-index only if it is needed. (remove all z-index and see what happens https://jsfiddle.net/uf78r0va/ ) If you need a z-index, then according to the structure of your snippet, give them the same value. Last ones will be drawned over the previous ones.

It looks like you just have incorrect z-index values. .overlay is set to 2000 and .custom-modal-background is only 1500, so it's behaving exactly as expected that it's showing up behind the overlay. If you adjust .custom-modal-background to a value of 2050 (between the 2000 for .overlay and the 2100 for .highlighted), it seems to render as you're expecting

The problem is, that if there are other elements in the custom modal, I want these to be covered as well if they are not highlighted. But they will be shown even if they don't have the highlighted class. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/pcown0g5/7/

Do you have 1 overlay and many modals on the page, or is there only one of each? Because you can make it work by putting the overlay inside the modal background, so they're in the same stacking context: https://jsfiddle.net/j5mtdgbz

@AaylaSecura this is a good idea. I will just need multiple overlays then, because sometimes the modal is not visible and I still want to be able to apply the overlay. I have multiple modals but I need to apply the overlay only over one of the modals.
